# SpringBoot Single Page Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Начал делать приложение и пытаюсь сделать single page application. Для этого я создал один маппинг на "/":

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

А для всех остальных запросов мне нужно сделать перенаправление на "/":

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public String forward() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Происходит взаимная рекурсия, как правильно замапить все запросы кроме "/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, таким образом:

```
@RequestMapping("/**/{path:[^\\.]+}")
public String forward() {
    return "forward:/";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```